# My c# code goes thorough all if statements although all of them are false

Tags: c#, if-statement, null, boolean

I have an attendancesheet program. I have triple checked my database tables and all of their columns are null. I said if they are not null go through but although all of them are null it goes through them all :D I don't know whats wrong.

```
private void textBoxX1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    sqlcon.Close();
    sqlcon.Open();

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        string t = lbl_Time.Text;
        string d = lbl_Date.Text;

        string selectQueryName = "SELECT name FROM tbl_attendanceMembers where memberCode=" + "'" + textBoxX1.Text + "'";
        var sqlcmdName = new SqlCommand(selectQueryName, sqlcon);
        var resultName = sqlcmdName.ExecuteScalar();

        string selectQueryId = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_attendanceSheet";
        var sqlcmdId = new SqlCommand(selectQueryId, sqlcon);
        var resultId = sqlcmdId.ExecuteScalar();

        (1)if (resultId != null)
        {
            string selectQueryCockin = "SELECT Clockin FROM tbl_attendanceSheet where id=" + "resultId";
            var sqlcmdCockin = new SqlCommand(selectQueryCockin, sqlcon);
            var resultCockin = sqlcmdId.ExecuteScalar();

           (2)if (resultCockin != null)
            {
                (3)if (resultName != null)
                {

                    this.lbl_mmbrname.Text = resultName.ToString();
                    this.lbl_timestored.Text = t;
                    textBoxX1.Clear();                       
                }    
            }
        }
        else //if result id == null
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmdClockin = new SqlCommand("InputClockIn", sqlcon);
            sqlcmdClockin.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmdClockin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputDate", d);
            sqlcmdClockin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputTime", t);
            sqlcmdClockin.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_attendanceMembers", sqlcon);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sqlda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        sqlcon.Close();

    }
}
```

When I execute this code, it equals `lbl_mmbrname.Text` to `resultName`  and `lbl_timestored.Text = t`. So it means it has gone through all the way down into the 3rd if statement which is false...

I have checked it via break poits(f9).

By the first `sqlcon.close();` is because if I dont write it it will say connection is not closed which doesn't make sense to me because I have written a `sqlcon.close();` down there...

Comment: Sure you want `+ "resultId"` and not `+ resultId`? Also do not use string concatenation to create queries. Use parameterized queries! This is susceptible for sql injections

Comment: wow my bad youre right.I have to correct that. would you lead me to a link about learning more and preventing SQL injection? thank you for your advice

Comment: easiest - type in google ;)

Comment: @GiladGreen yes your right thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Common_DbCommand_ExecuteScalar) if on a `DbCommand.ExecuteScalar()`the database returns null your query gets a [DbNull.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.7.2) object returned. 
So I guess you need to check for that instead of `null`

**EDIT**
Relevant remark there:

> If the first column of the first row in the result set is not found, a null reference is returned. If the value in the database is null, the query returns DBNull.Value.

so it can return both a `null` and `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Thanks for the edit! There was a follow-up question by the OP because I didn't post a full answer.